# How to directly add file to zip in python?

Tags: python, zip

I am new to python. Here my target is to put data into a file in zip. Following is the code I have written, in which I am write data to a unzipped_file, then writing unzipped_file in zipped_file.zip and then removing unzipped file.

```
import os
import zipfile

##Some code above.............
for some_data in big_data:
    with open('unzipped_file', 'a+') as unzipped_f:
        unzipped_f.write(some_data)

##Some code in between...........

with zipfile.ZipFile('zipped_file.zip', 'w') as zipped_f:
    zipped_f.write("unzipped_file")

os.remove("unzipped_file")
```

Instead of creating an intermediate unzipped_file. Can I directly write my data in zipped_file in one step.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`zipfile.writestr(file_name, bytes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) writes  raw data represented by `bytes` into an archive.  `file_name` is the name of a file the archive will contain.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('zipped_file.zip', 'w') as zipped_f:
    zipped_f.writestr("file_name", some_data)
```

**EDIT:** the only thing you can do to write multiple pieces of data to some file in an archive is to write all of it at once:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('zipped_file.zip', 'w') as zipped_f:
    zipped_f.writestr("file_name", ''.join(x for x in big_data))
```

The method above will work only if `big_data` contains strings. Otherwise you could try `pickle.dumps(big_data)` or `pickle.dumps(list(big_data))`.

Note that then a copy of `big_data` (unless it's a generator) will be constructed in memory and then written to a file. It's impossible to update a file inside an existing `ZipFile` archive without extracting it and then zipping again.

Comment: Sorry for the mis-communication, but here I am trying to append data into one unzipped_file then keeping it in zipped_file. I have edited the code for reference

Answer (score 9):

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects), You could use:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('someZipFile.zip', 'a') as myzip:
    myzip.write('someFileToBeAdded.txt')
```

to add `someFileToBeAdded.txt` to existing `someZipFile.zip` file. If `someZipFile.zip` doesn't exist, it will be created.

Comment: It'is recommended to use `with statement` with files.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, although main focus here was on adding file to zip file, rather than 'correct' way to open file.

Comment: Sorry for the mis-communication, but here I am trying to append data into one unzipped_file then keeping it in zipped_file. I have edited the code for reference